# Recycle Bin Duration

Tags: recycle-bin

[Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm) says that

> The Recycle Bin link in the sidebar lets you view and restore recently deleted records for 15 days before they are permanently deleted.

However, in my clients Org I can see:

[image: Recycle Bin picture]

Those are objects in the recycle bin from 28 days ago.

Is the documentation on the Recycle Bin out of date, or are these entries that are kept in the recycle bin log, but not restorable?